# Uploading Files from Laravel App to BitBucket

Tags: laravel, git, ssh

Here is what im try to achieve, I have a laravel app with a `BitBucket` repo in my laravel project public directory `(public/repo.name)`.

Now what i want is to run, `git add .` `git commit -m "Changes"` and `git push` from my `(public/repo.name)` directory inside my laravel app.

I want the git commands to run when i go to lets say, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/deploy` this would only deploy whatever changes are in `(public/repo.name)`

Answer (score 0):

Convert your Project to a Git Project
Open your terminal and navigate to the project root directory and run the `git init` command.

```
git init
git-init-laravel-project
Git init Laravel project
Git Add and Commit All Files
```

With the `git init` command we have successfully converted our project into a local git project. Although we have not yet added a git remote to our project.

As a second step lets go ahead and add and commit all the files to our local git repository.

Run the `git add` and `git commit` command on the project root.

```
git add .

git commit -m "First Commit"
```

The `git add` command adds a change in the working directory to the staging area. It tells Git that you want to include updates to a particular file in the next commit.

The `git commit` command commits the staged snapshot to the project history. Committed snapshots can be thought of as “safe” versions of a project—Git will never change them unless you explicitly ask it to.

Git add and Git commit on Laravel project
Create a New BitBucket Repository
We are now ready to push our changes to a remote repository. But before that we have to create a repository where we can push our changes.

Login to Bitbucket if you already have an account or SignUp for a new account. On the left hand menu , Click on the `+` symbol to get the option of Creating a New Repository.

Create Bitbucket empty Repo for Laravel.

Enter a suitable project name and click on Create Repository. A blank repository will be created and you will be redirected to the overview page of the repo.

Now we can go ahead and make this repo our remote repo for the Laravel project.

Add Remote Repo and Push Changes
To add the repository you just created as the remote repo for your local Laravel project. Run the following command on your project root in terminal.

`git remote add origin https://<repo_owner>@bitbucket.org/<accountname>/<reponame>.git`

Replace the `repo_owner` and `accountname` in the URL accordingly.

```
git-laravel-remote-add
git remote add laravel
```

Now we can go ahead and push the changes to remote repository.

```
git push -u origin master
git-laravel-push-bitbucket
Git push Laravel project
```

If you see at source in your bitbucket repository. You should see your Laravel directory structure along with the files.

Comment: Thankyou so much, but what im trying to do is to host the laravel app say newsite.com and then run all the git push commands from laravel controller say newsite.com/deploy